# Execute based on values of different data types in different columns of a data frame | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to loop through all items in a column.

If it meets the condition in the column then check to see,
If another condition is met in a different column.

The data types in the two columns are different, one is an integer & the other a string that I am checking for.

I am not sure where I have gone wrong & all information I've found online so far is about creating new columns based on data from a column.

Here is a simplified version of the code I am using.

```
import pandas as pd

servercount = 0
othercount = 0

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'operatingsystem': ['Windows 7', 'Windows Server 2012', 'Windows Server 2012 R', 
                'macOSX', 'Linux Server'],
    'login': [9, 12, 5, 11, 19],
})


for i in df['login']:
    if i > 10:
        if i in df['operatingsystem'].str.lower().str.contains("server"):
            servercount += 1
        else:
            othercount += 1

print("Servers:", servercount, "\nOthers:", othercount)
```

Currently this returns 0 on the servercount & 3 on the othercount meaning that it is not detecting the word server in the operatingsystem column.

Comment: @murariprasad I am using 'str.lower()' so that everything is converted to lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create mask wich chain both masks toghether by `&` bot bitwise `AND` and for count use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last select `True` and `False` values:

```
m = (df['login'] > 10) & df['operatingsystem'].str.contains("server", case=False, na=False)
print (m.value_counts())
False    3
True     2
dtype: int64


out = m.value_counts()

print("Servers:", out[True], "\nOthers:", out[False])
Servers: 2 
Others: 3
```

EDIT: Because need 3 counts are created 3 mask separately, `~` is for invert mask (same like `mask == False`):

```
m1 = df['login'] > 10 
m2 =  df['operatingsystem'].str.contains("server", case=False, na=False)

print("Servers greater 10:", (m1 & m2).sum(), 
      "\nServers less 10:", (m1 & ~m2).sum(), 
      "\nOthers:", (~m1).sum())
Servers greater 10: 2 
Servers less 10: 1 
Others: 2
```

Comment: This is great thank you , but I've realised that I've made a blunder with my question. What I actually need is three counts, one for the servers over a certain integer (in the example's case 10), another one for all other operating systems over 10 & a final one for anything else.

Comment: @Harry - answer was edited.

Comment: This works perfectly for the test code, but in my real code I am getting the error for the print line: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'. I think this might be because in my real code the 'login' column contains large numbers stored as floats

Comment: @Harry Answer was edited, added `na=False` to `str.contains`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the final number (as in total servercount and othercount), then consider simply passing the logics to your dataframe. You are iterating over `i` only with is `df['Login']`, nowhere are you using `operatingsystem` values.

```
servercount = ((df['login'] > 10) & \
           (df['operatingsystem'].str.contains("server",
                                               case=False,
                                               regex=True))).sum()
```

Then, by difference you can calculate `othercount`:

```
othercount = len(df) - servercount
```